# Calculate average ratings in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, average

How do I calculate the average rating using Reactjs? My website has consists of only React and an RSS Feed.

Step by step I guess it would have to:
- Store the ratings
- Add them up to a total rating score
- Keep track of the number of ratings
- Divide the total rating by n

I'm just starting to learn React and I have no idea if that's even possible without having a rails backend... Could someone just point me in the right direction??

---

Edit: What I currently have is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import StarRatingComponent from 'react-star-rating-component';

class App extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
     super();

     this.state = {
         rating: 1
     };
 }

 onStarClick(name, value) {
     this.setState({rating: value});
 }

 render() {
     const { rating } = this.state;
     return (
         <div>
             <h2>Rating from state: {rating}</h2>
             <StarRatingComponent
                 name="rate1"
                 starCount={10}
                 value={rating}
                 onStarClick={this.onStarClick.bind(this)}
             />
         </div>
       );
    }
  }

 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

 export default App;
```

This is working, but I don't know how to store it without having a database/seeds file (like I said, no experience with JS/React). I'm also nowhere near getting an average rating. Any ideas or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't only have React, you also have JavaScript and all its functionality, which will bring you pretty far already. What have you tried so far?

Comment: what version of React are you using? it's ReactDom.render in the latest versions.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks, it got rid of that error. I'm now getting another one though; ReferenceError: ReactDom is not defined

Comment: Ok, so it was actually ReactDOM.render, and I forgot to export. The basic star rating is working now. I still have no idea how to get the average rating though...